# Including DetailView context in ListView page in the Order history page using Django

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-templates, django-views

Hi Djangonauts,

I would like to add some Order details(DetailView) in the Order history page(ListView), See image example below ( I have made the image on photoshop). I was able to get the grey part (order list to show) But I am not able to get the item details to show in this page. If I click `View Order Detail` it goes to detail page where I can show all this. But I need a small summary in the ListPage too see example below

[image]

below are my **view.py**

```
class OrderHistory(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = Order
    template_name = 'order/order_list.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(OrderHistory, self).get_context_data()
        context['order_details'] = Order.objects.filter(emailAddress=self.request.user.email)
        context['order_items'] = OrderItem.objects.filter(order=self.kwargs.get("order"))
        return context
```

I even tried 
`# context['order_items'] = OrderItem.objects.filter(order__id=self.kwargs.get("order.id"))`

Below are my **models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class Order(models.Model):
    token = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True)
    total = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, verbose_name='USD Order Total')
    emailAddress = models.EmailField(max_length=100, blank=True, verbose_name='Email Address')
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    billingName = models.CharField(max_length=350, blank=True)
    billingAddress1 = models.CharField(max_length=350, blank=True)
    billingCity = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    billingZipcode = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True)
    billingCountry = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)


class OrderItem(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, verbose_name='USD Price')
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

        def sub_total(self):
        return self.quantity * self.price
```

I am also attaching my Product model below. Just in case if you need to see

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='product', blank=True)
    stock = models.IntegerField(default=True)
```

Below are my **templates** Its not needed for this question. I believe I am doing something wrong in the views.py . But I have it just in case.

```
    {% extends 'base.html' %}
    {% load staticfiles %}
    {% block body %}
        <div>
            <div class="text-center">
                <br/>
                <h1 class="text-center my_title">Tasting Order Purchase History</h1>
                <br/>
                {% if order_details %}
                    {% for order in order_details %}
                    <div class="row order_detail_div" >
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <b>Order Number: 156{{ order.id }}</b><br/>
                            <small><em>Order Date: {{ order.created|date:"M d Y" }}</em></small>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-1"></div>
                        <div class="col-md-3 text-left">
                            <b>Status: Paid</b><br/>
                            <b>Total items in Order: ()</b>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-1"></div>
                        <div class="col-md-3 order_total_text">
                            <b>Order Total: ${{ order.total }}</b>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2 view_order_details">
                            <b><a href="{% url 'order:order_detail' order.id %}">View Order Details</a></b>
                        </div>
                    </div>
<!--------------------------This is the code for OrderItem that's not working------->
                    {% for item in order_items %}
                    <div class="row order_item_detail_div">
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            a <!--This a does not show either -->
                            <img src="{{ item.product.image }}" >
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    {% endfor %}
<!--------------------------Code ends here ----------------------------------->

                {% endfor %}

            {% else %}
                <p>
                    You do not have any orders yet.<br/><br/>
                    <a href="{% url 'home' %}" class="btn btn-secondary">Add more recipes</a>
                </p>
            {% endif %}
        </div>
    </div>
    <br/>
        <br/>
    {% endblock %}
```

Any advise on how I can make this work

Comment: Question is still not clear about your Goals.. can you elaborate about your final Goals

Comment: @DeepakSharma I am sorry if I was not clear. My final goal is in the image that I have attached above. I have 2 models `Order` and `OrderItem`. `OrderItem` has a foreign key `Order` (see models above). The image that you see above is the Order page. The grey part is the `Order` ListView. It shows all the Orders. and when I click on the View details button. It will take the user to the detail view. which will show what all items are in the Order. (That is easy I can do that). But I need some details of the OrderItem to show on the Order History page too. As you can see in the image.

Answer (score 1):

In your template you try to show an image that doesn't exist as your product field is a CharField so does not have an image field associated with it. Is product on your OrderItem model supposed to be a ForeignKey to a product model?

Note that you need to call the url() method on the image in your template, i.e. {{ product.image.url }}. See the docs on FileField here: 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#filefield

In your template try to show item.price or quantity as text fields to prove that your query set is working.

Comment: awesome I got what I was doing wrong Product had to a Foreign key. Thank you so much that was so simple. What was I thinking. I have been breaking my head on this since morning

Comment: hi Simon I fixed the models and I have been working on resolving this but I still am not able to fix this. any further steps